# Search Filter needed to find a user with networkID in Active Directory

Tags: java, spring, authentication, active-directory, ldap

Updated 5/28/2019

I'm using `ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider` from `org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad` and `searchForUser` method is able to find the user by email.

I'm using the default `searchFilter`: `(&(objectClass=user)(userPrincipalName={0}))`.

But it doesn't work if networkID is provided as username. So:

`employee@PublicCompanyEmail.com`  works fine

`employee_AD_username@internaldomain.com` doesn't work

Appreciate any ideas on it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little bit of terminology first

Security Account Manager (SAM) Name

```
  The networkID you use to login to the network.
```

User Principal Name (UPN)

```
 It may be Implicit UPN (iUPN) or Explicit UPN (eUPN).

 An example for iUPN would be: networkID@internalDomain.com

 An example for eUPN would be: employee_name@companyName.com

 eUPN may be defined by network administrator.

 In my case, the UPN we're using in our AD is actually an eUPN.
```

Search Filter Syntax

```
 This is query language for AD.

 We used it to define the filter while searching for objects in AD.

 {0}-occurrence means full username with domain in it. If the domain is defined in LDAP configuration then Spring Security checks if it's present in the entered username to login. If not, then it'll be added.

 {1}-occurrence means whatever entered as username. So, Spring won't do any modification on the provided username.
```

If you want to be able to login without providing domain name, you need to define the domain in LDAP configuration

```
ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider provider = new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider(
            "domain",...);
```

Then if it's the domain used in email address, this filter:

```
(&(objectClass=user)(userPrincipalName={0}))
```

will find the user with and without the domain name.

Then if the configured domain is internal-domain, this filter:

```
(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName={1}))
```

will find the user if the username provided is networkID with no doamin.

If you don't define the domain for LDAP configuration and leave it null while instantiating the object, then you should be able to search for both UPN and sam -account with {1} occurrence but you have to provide the domain for both networkID and email-username while on login.

Answer (score 1):

Har har, you tripped into the eUPN vs. iUPN issues. Your company works with UPN suffixes which creates a virtual domain with a virtual enterprise UPN for each user stored in the `userPrincipalName` field. As soon as the implicit UPN (Kerberos principal) is overridden with the enterprise one, you are out of luck.

You may want consider something better than nagging your users with username and password over and over again...at least on Tomcat you can have [this](http://tomcatspnegoad.sourceforge.net/) if you can live with `<security:jee>` in Spring Security.

Comment: Awesome hint! But should iUPN get overridden by eUPN? Shouldn't they both stay available?

Comment: Actually we have apps here allowing login with both iUPN and eUPN. Our Jenkins server works like that. But on Jira, we have just eUPN working and the same with the webapp I'm working on.

So, it sounds more like an app configuration issue than a network thing.

I'm going to update the question after what I learned from your answer to make it more specific.

Comment: @Alireza don't confuse bind principal with the attribute you use to filter. Active Directory accepts both for binding, but the search will yield 0 results.

Comment: But why iUPN works when I update bind principal to email address manually in debug mode?

Comment: again, bind takes either, LDAP query not. You should have a look at it the LDAP request via Wireshark. This will give you answers.

Comment: Thanks! Going for it.